# Flutter Riverpod does not catch List<Map>'s nested value changes

Tags: flutter, riverpod

```
final filterProvider = StateProvider<List<Map>>((ref) => [
      {'text': 'rating', 'onOrOff': true},
      {'text': 'km', 'onOrOff': true},
    ]);
```

I have this filterProvider. And I am trying to update the value of 'onOrOff'.

`ref.watch(filterProvider.notifier).state[i]['onOrOff'] = onOffVal;`

When I do this way, Riverpod does not change the value immediately, how can I adjust the value and make Riverpod to apply changes right away?

Comment: Creating a new list or observing only the map inside the list aren't possible in your usecase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `riverpod` the `state` provided with a `StateProvider` is supposed to be immutable. You cannot modify it, you need to re-assign it.

You can read

> It is typically used for:
>
> - exposing an **immutable** state which can change over time after reacting to custom events.
> - centralizing the logic for modifying some state (aka "business logic") in a single place, improving maintainability over time.

in [riverpod's documentation](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_notifier_provider)

```dart
final filter = [...ref.read(filterProvider)]; // Copies the list.
filter[i]['onOrOff'] = onOffVal;
ref.read(filterProvider.notifier).state = filter;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is part of why StateNotifier and StateProvider should not be used in modern Riverpod applications.  Instead, you should be constructing a Notifier-based provider, and provide mutation methods to update your state.  The Notifier can use combinations of assigning to state (as the previous StateNotifier did) and/or calling ref.notifyListeners() (as the previous ChangeNotifier did).

But please, stop using StateNotifier, ChangeNotifier, and StateProvider with Riverpod!  They are all effectively deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am looking into it now. Just one question tho, even if it is for a simple string, should I not use StateProvider? On the document of Riverpod saying that it can be use for like simple thing such as 'boolean' or 'string'?

Comment: Generally no.  Exposing a .state is now viewed as a mis-design and should be avoided.

Comment: Sorry to bother you one more time. https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/providers/notifier_provider I am looking at this example. Should I create a '.dart' file for each provider I create?

Comment: Dart doesn't care about files.  Put your entire app in one file, or one top-level entry per file.  Doesn't matter, except for library boundaries.